# Get Woocommerce product category image url

Tags: php, wordpress, image, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I have used the code following to get the thumbnail URL of a Woocommerce product category but it only outputs just the `<img>` tag with `src="unknown"`.

```
$cat_slug = t-shirts;
$thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat_slug, 'thumbnail_id', true );
$image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
echo '<img src="'.$image.'" alt="" width="50" height="50" />';
```

What is the best approach to make it work?

**Edit**

In the second call for thumbnail for the jean category it just outputs `<img src(unknown) alt="" width="50" height="50" />`.

```
<div class="list-item">
    <div class="item-img">

        <?php

        $term_slug    = 't-shirts';
        $taxonomy     = "product_cat";
        $term_id      = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy )->term_id;
        $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
        $image        = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );

        echo '<img src="'.$image.'" alt="" width="50" height="50" />';

        ?>

</div>

<a href="#">
    <div class="item-name">
        <?php if( $term = get_term_by('slug', 't-shirts', 'product_cat') ) echo $term->name;?>
    </div>
</a>

</div>

<div class="list-item">
    <div class="item-img">

        <?php

        $term_slug    = 'jeans';
        $taxonomy     = "product_cat";
        $term_id      = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy )->term_id;
        $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
        $image        = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );

        echo '<img src="'.$image.'" alt="" width="50" height="50" />';

        ?>

</div>

<a href="#">
    <div class="item-name">
    <?php if( $term = get_term_by('slug', 'jeans', 'product_cat') ) echo $term->name;?>
    </div>
</a>

</div>
```

Comment: just the img tag with src="unknown". I have edited the question. Thanks

Comment: `$cat_slug = 't-shirts';`. Make this change

Comment: same result. It outputs `<img src=(unknown) alt="" width="50" height="50"> without the image url.`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function `get_woocommerce_term_meta()` needs the term ID instead of the term slug. So you can use `get_term_by()` Wordpress function to get the term ID from a term slug.

So your code will be:

```
$term_slug    = 't-shirts';
$taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
$term_id      = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy )->term_id;
$thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
$image        = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );

// Output
echo '<img src="'.$image.'" alt="" width="50" height="50" />';
```

Tested and works

---

**Addition rev 3** (related to your comment)

I have make some other changes using a foreach loop optimizing the code and allowing you **to add as many product category slugs as you want**.

I have also added the term link, and make some minor changes.

```
<?php
$term_slugs   = array('jeans', 't-shirts');
$taxonomy     = "product_cat";

// Loop though the term slugs array
foreach ( $term_slugs as $term_slug ):
    $term        = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy );
    if( $term ):
        $term_link   = get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy );

        $thumb_id    = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
        $img_src     = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb_id );
        ?>
        <div class="list-item">
            <div class="item-image">
                <img src="<?php echo $img_src; ?>" alt="" width="50" height="50" />
            </div>
            <div class="item-name">
                <a href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif;
endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It works fine. However, I need to show thumbnails of two categories on the same page. So I have used this piece of code two times and in the second one I changed `$term_slug` to `'jeans';`. But the problem is category image for jeans doesn't show. It outputs `<img src(unknown) alt="" width="50" height="50" />`. Any help is really appreciated

Comment: I just added the code as an edit. Sorry for the long markup!

Comment: @sparkinglabs I have updated again the addition at thend of my answer (revision 3). There is also now the term link and some minor changes.

Answer (score 2):

`get_woocommerce_term_meta` has `term_id` as first parameter. Refer [Here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-get_woocommerce_term_meta.html)

Code something like this

```
$termId = 1;
$thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $termId, 'thumbnail_id', true );
```

OR

To get thumbnail from slug name, You have to fetch term ID by using `get_term_by`. You can refer [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by)

```
$termName = 't-shirts';
$category = get_term_by('name', $termName, 'product_cat');

$termId = $category->term_id;
$thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $termId, 'thumbnail_id', true );
$image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
echo '<img src="'.$image.'" alt="" width="50" height="50" />';
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks. Is there any way I could use a slug there?

Comment: Just for info, the Woocommerce product category custom taxonomy is not "category" but **"product_cat"**. The taxonomy "category" is used by WordPress on normal posts (as the blog posts)…